# Can't install pyperclip python3 Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pyperclip

I'm trying to run pyperclip module in PyCharm on Mac OS X. I've imported it and got a traceback error. I tried reinstalling it in terminal and it displayed `collecting packages` but I still get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/numberEmailRetractor/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyperclip, re
ImportError: No module named pyperclip
```

Comment: Please see this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164669/pycharm-importerror-no-module-named-x