# PyCharm doesn't see locally installed package

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I created a small Python package and pip3 installed it.  Made sure the package was installed to `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/`

Fired up PyCharm with the hope of using my newly created python package, I go the the project settings, project interpreter and attempt to add the package; however, the package is not listed in the "available packages."

Did a `pip3 list` and the package was listed.

Did I miss a step somewhere?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried VSCode? Forget PyCharm... [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) is the way to go. Here is the [getting started](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/raw-tech/Beginners-Guide-to-VS-Code) -- it's the only (freeware!) editor that's superior to both NPP and Sublime.

Comment: You need to setup pycharm project interpreter properly. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164670/9871463

Comment: `Available packages` contains packages that are available to install, if your package has already been installed, then it should be in `Project Interpreter` window.