# Pycharm modulenotfounderror not installing to sitepackages

Tags: python, pycharm

When I use pip install, the package ends up here:
[image: https://i.snag.gy/ixqMHL.jpg]

And I get a moduleNotFoundError in pycharm. However, if I manually move the folder into the "site-packages" folder, it works.

Comment: "ends up here:" and where is that?

Comment: Please see if this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164670/9871463