# import says no module named 'can' but library is installed in site-packages?

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-10, python-can

First and foremost, I'm on windows.

PyCharm says `No module named 'can'`, but I can clearly see the `can` module when I open *Module Docs* and it's listed under `site-packages`.  I'm not sure why PyCharm is saying the `can` module isn't there.

Why would it say this if it's clearly there?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164670/9871463). I think you installed it via pip or you are using wrong _Python Project Interpreter_. And if answer helps, please upvote it. Thank you