# ModuleNotFound:No module named'imutils'

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6, imutils

I have already installed imutils using pip (which is upgraded to the latest version), and it's supposed to be on PyCharm ExternalModules directly after installation , but whenever I try to run my program that uses imutils modules it prints: Modulerror: imutils is not found, what to do? 
This is what I get as an output:

```
**/home/manel/.virtualenvs/tutorialpoint/bin/python /home/manel/Documents/opencv-tutorial/opencv_tutorial_01.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manel/Documents/opencv-tutorial/opencv_tutorial_01.py", line 5, in <module>
    import imutils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'**
```

Comment: Can you please share more details, or the image depicting complete details of the error?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I have updated my question, you'll see what was the output exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter`. If it's not listed there, it's not installed on virtual env PyCharm is using. You can install it with `+` sign next to to listed packages. Just search it and press *Install package*.

*P.S.* You can read my Q&A at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164670/9871463) for more detailed info about this specific problem.

Comment: I followed these steps and it worked! thanks a lot!!